# RNN LSTM valueError while training

Tags: python, numpy, keras, deep-learning, lstm

Hi there recently I've been working on a RNN LSTM project and I have e 2D data set like

```
x = [[x1,x2,x3...,x18],[x1,x2,x3...,x18],...]
y = [[y1,y2,y3],[y1,y2,y3],...]

X.shape => (295,5,18)
Y.shape => (295,3)
```

and I convert it to a 3D dataset by code below

```
X_train = []
Y_train = []

for i in range(5,300):
    X_train.append(training_set_scaled[i-5:i,0:18])
    Y_train.append(training_set_scaled[i,18:22])
    
X_train, Y_train = np.array(X_train), np.array(Y_train)
```

and then use Keras for LSTM

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.layers import LSTM
from keras.layers import Dropout

regressor = Sequential()

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True,input_shape=(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.1))

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.1))

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.1))

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.1))

regressor.add(LSTM(units=50))
regressor.add(Dropout(0.1))


regressor.add(Dense(units= 1))

regressor.compile(optimizer= 'adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')

regressor.fit(X_train,Y_train, epochs = 100, batch_size = 32)
```

and when I run this script I got the error below:

`ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer lstm_104: expected ndim=3, found ndim=4`

I have no idea about the problem can any body help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change:

```
input_shape=(X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])
```

to

```
input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])
```

Basically `keras` is designed to take any number of examples in a single batch, so it automatically puts `None` as the first parameter. So, when you mention the rest 2 dimensions, it gets a `3` dimensional input in total, but if you yourself mention the first dimension, the number of the dimensions becomes `4`, i.e, `(None, X_train.shape[0],X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])`.

But again, if you really want to hard code the batch_size you can still do it. For this, you have to use `batch_input_shape` instead of `input_shape` like follow:

```
regressor.add(LSTM(units=50, return_sequences=True, batch_input_shape=(X_train.shape[0], X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])))
```

It will give you the power to control which specific batch size to set for the network. (Your program has another flaw in this case, you are setting the batch size `X_train.shape[0]` which is `295`, but you are sending `32` in `fit()`, but they should be equal. Also batch size is generally taken lesser than the data set size).

Comment: Thank you very much! That worked for me. I would like to ask one more question: what do you prefer for starting and understanding Keras? Is Keras documentation good enough? Would you suggest any specific part of it? Furthermore, would you recommend any sort of tutorial or handbook for this matter?

Comment: @radinvafaei alright, `keras` is now merged with `tensorflow`. The documentation (https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras) is good. But I shall suggest you to visit the corresponding `github` repository as well, if the documentation doesn't seem to be clear enough. This will help you get the insight what is happening behind the scene and will remove many confusions.

Comment: @radinvafaei if you want to learn more about `keras` I shall suggest you this: https://www.coursera.org/specializations/tensorflow2-deeplearning#courses course. This is one of the best courses I have found on this topic. I myself have learnt a lot from this.

Comment: @radinvafaei now talking about book. If you want to learn more on `machin learning` and `deep learning` you can read this book (https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/hands-on-machine-learning/9781492032632/), it is one of the best books I have ever read on this topic. You will love it.